# How to redirect from old standard wordpress permalink structure to new custom one

Tags: permalinks

I have changed my permalink structure for my WordPress blog from

```
http://www.example.com/2017/07/29/sample-post/

www.example.com/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/sample-post-20170729

www.example.com/%postname%-%year%%monthnum%%day%
```

Is there any way to redirect the links from old permalink structure to the new custom one.

Note: WordPress didn't handle the redirection.

Comment: the permalinks admin section should handle this, how did you make these changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Redirection plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) from Wordpress plugin directory. It's FREE.